# Mapping Disease Incidence in the Northeast in R

Tags: r, county

I am trying to map disease incidence by county in states in northeastern states in the US. I have the shapefiles for the entire US but I am having a difficult time deleting the states that I do not need. Here is what I have so far:

```
soco <- readShapePoly("tl_2014_us_county.shp")
summary(soco)  
soco.df <- data.frame(soco)

# Change row name from default to FIPS. I am trying to delete states based on FIPS.
row.names(soco)<-as.character(soco$GEOID)
row.names(soco)

# NAME has a unique 2 number state identifier.
# I am trying to delete the states I do not need based on this number.
ne<-soco[soco$NAME-(31,26 etc), ]
```

Comment: Do not change rownames!!!! You will break the relationship between the "data" slot and the rest of the spatial object. You do not need to delete by rowname, just access the attribute. Follow the example provided by @cengel where an attribute is queried in the data.frame object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the TIGER file from here: http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/COUNTY/tl_2014_us_county.zip
you can do this:

```
# use rgdal to read read in the shapefile to preserve projection information
library(rgdal)
soco <- readOGR(".", "tl_2014_us_county")

# use soco$STATEFP to find states, SpatialPolygonsDataFrame behaves like a data frame
ne <- soco[!soco$STATEFP %in% c(31,26), ] #removing Nebraska and Kentucky
```

You may want to google subsetting data frames in R, there are many resources.